# C: Find occurrences of bytes in region of memory

Tags: c, pointers, byte

I am trying to write a function which uses only pointer-based logic to search through a region of memory (baseAddr) for a certain byte (Byte), counts the occurrences, and stores the offsets in an array (Offsets). Here is what I have so far:

```
uint8_t findBytes( uint16_t* const Offsets, const uint8_t* const baseAddr,
                                            uint32_t length, uint8_t Byte) {
    uint8_t bytesRead = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (bytesRead < length) {
        if ((baseAddr + bytesRead) == Byte) {
            *(Offsets + count) = bytesRead;
            count++;
        }
        bytesRead++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

For whatever reason, I always get stuck in an infinite loop if I use (bytesRead < length). Length is always 1024. What exactly is wrong with this code? I am still learning the proper uses of pointers, so I'm 99% sure it's to do with that.

Comment: what's the maximum value for variables of type `uint8_t`?

Comment: A simple `printf` of state variables would reveal this bug in a minute.

Comment: That makes sense for the infinite loop! Completely forgot it's only 255. I changed it, and now the issue is that it keeps finding 0 occurrences and not storing any offsets, even though there are definite occurrences in the memory region.

Comment: Do not change the answered question! Rolled back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bytesRead` is a `uint8_t`,  which has a maximum value of 255. If you have a `uint32_t length`, your offset should be the same data type. And since potentially every byte could be a match, your count (return value) also needs to be the same type, as does the offsets array.

More problems:

```
if ((baseAddr + bytesRead) == Byte)
```

You're not dereferencing the pointer here, you're only checking its value. Your compiler should be issuing a warning here for the type mismatch.

Try:

```
if (*(baseAddr + bytesRead) == Byte)
```

Finally, you need to make sure `offsets` points at enough memory. Again, potentially *every byte could match, which means `offsets` should be the same length (in elements) as the input data.

Comment: Thank you! I do not understand pointers as well as I should. I changed bytesRead to a uint32_t and it solved the infinite loop problem, and the issue with comparing was solved with your solution as well.

Comment: @SamTyson if an answer helped you solve your problem, then it would be appreciated to upvote it and then click the gray check mark to make it the accepted answer.